# numpy is not a supported wheel on the platform

Tags: python, numpy

I get the error as "numpy is not a supported wheel on this platform"
I tried to install numpy of 32 as well as 64 bit but both failed. My system is 64 bit.

I tried to get the answer from this website but all in vain.
Following is the answer i got.

```
import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
[('cp27', 'cp27m', 'win32'), ('cp27', 'none', 'win32'), ('py2', 'none', 'win32'), ('cp27', 'none', 'any'), ('cp2', 'none', 'any'), ('py27', 'none', 'any'), ('py2', 'none', 'any'), ('py26', 'none', 'any'), ('py25', 'none', 'any'), ('py24', 'none', 'any'), ('py23', 'none', 'any'), ('py22', 'none', 'any'), ('py21', 'none', 'any'), ('py20', 'none', 'any')]
>>> import platform; print(platform.platform())
Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
```

How do I install numpy in python?

Comment: did you try directly entering `python -m pip install numpy` into cmd?

Comment: If it is permissable in your situation, consider simply reinstalling Python by means of one of the scientific Python distributions, e.g. Anaconda Python. Here, NumPy (and many other useful packages for scientific computation) is installed by default.

Comment: Yes, R.S. Nikhil Krishna

Comment: Could you help me out with this? I tried it again, got the same error @R.S.NikhilKrishna

Comment: You can try uninstalling your version of python and installing the latest version from their website

Comment: Yes, reinstalled. Still doesn't work. @R.S.NikhilKrishna@jmd_dk

Comment: @AditiYerudkar -Was this issue resolved? I'm facing the same on my system. Please suggest.